# Calling a method on a function definition in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, ember.js

How would you translate this snippet of javascript to coffeescript?  Specifically I'm struggling with how to call `.property()` on the function definition.

```
MyApp.president = SC.Object.create({
  firstName: "Barack",
  lastName: "Obama",

  fullName: function() {
    return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName');

    // Call this flag to mark the function as a property
  }.property('firstName', 'lastName')
});
```

Comment: Good practice is to declare your property dependencies. In your case you would do `property('firstName', 'lastName')`. If you have declared your dependencies you can also set your property to be cached with `.cacheable()`.

Comment: @Peter Wagenet - Good point, I updated the code for future searchers.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think this is how you're supposed to write it:

```
MyApp.president = SC.Object.create {
  firstName: "Barack",
  lastName: "Obama",
  fullName: (-> 
    return @get 'firstName' + ' ' + @get 'lastName'
    # Call this flag to mark the function as a property
  ).property('firstName', 'lastName')
}
```

[checkout this link](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#try%3a%0AMyApp.president%20=%20SC.Object.create%20%7B%0A%20%20firstName%3a%20%22Barack%22,%0A%20%20lastName%3a%20%22Obama%22,%0A%20%20fullName%3a%20%28-%3E%20%0A%20%20%20%20return%20@get%20%27firstName%27%20+%20%27%20%27%20+%20@.get%20%27lastName%27%0A%20%20%20%20#%20Call%20this%20flag%20to%20mark%20the%20function%20as%20a%20property%0A%20%20%29.property%28%29%0A%7D)

Comment: Your property should depend on the underlying attributes changes, in order to have the computed property bound to any change. Otherwise, when first or last name will change, full name will no more reflect reality.

I submitted an edit...

Comment: This is the generated js code:

App.president = Ember.Object.create({
name: "Barack Obama",
firstName: "Barack",
lastName: "Obama",
fullName: (function() {
return "" + (this.get('firstName')) + " " + (this.get('lastName'));
}).property('firstName', 'lastName')
});

And when i run it in the console i get: "TypeError: App.president.fullName is not a function `App.president.fullName()` @0"

Comment: @bonyiii You should not be running it as a function. You should use `get('fullName')` instead.

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple ways to define computed properties. Here are examples of each:

```
MyApp.president = Ember.Object.create
  firstName: "Barack"
  lastName: "Obama"
  fullName: (-> 
    @get 'firstName' + ' ' + @get 'lastName'
  ).property('firstName', 'lastName')

MyApp.president = Ember.Object.create
  firstName: "Barack"
  lastName: "Obama"
  fullName: Ember.computed(-> 
    @get 'firstName' + ' ' + @get 'lastName'
  ).property('firstName', 'lastName')
```

Comment: The .property() call at the end is redundant.

Comment: I added the dependent keys. They aren't redundant when they're specified.

Answer (score 2):

When using Ember.computed, you do not need to call .property() so you can use this form as well:

```
MyApp.president = Ember.Object.create
  firstName: "Barack"
  lastName: "Obama"
  fullName: Ember.computed -> @get 'firstName' + ' ' + @get 'lastName'
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work?

```
 (() => this.get("firstName") * this.get("lastName")).property()
```

Comment: There's no need for the fat-arrow binding to `this`. Indeed, that will hurt, since it will bind to the declaring scope, not the object itself.