# Adding a function call on the end of function in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript, ember.js

Any ideas on how to write this as coffeescript?

```
Person = Ember.Object.extend({
  // these will be supplied by `create`
  firstName: null,
  lastName: null,

  fullName: function() {
    var firstName = this.get('firstName');
    var lastName = this.get('lastName');

   return firstName + ' ' + lastName;
  }.property('firstName', 'lastName')
});
```

I'm particularly interested in the `}.property` part of the code.  I can't figure out how to write this in coffeescript.

Comment: Is the `}.property` really supposed to be `},property`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling a method on a function definition in coffeescript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464739/calling-a-method-on-a-function-definition-in-coffeescript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

personally, i like braces around my functions:

```
Person = Ember.Object.extend(
  firstName: null
  lastName: null
  fullName: (->
    firstName = @get("firstName")
    lastName = @get("lastName")
    firstName + " " + lastName
  ).property("firstName", "lastName")
)
```

my head can better parse this ;-)

Answer (score -1):

first [jsbeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) it, then [js2coffee](http://js2coffee.org/) it:

```
Person = Ember.Object.extend(
  firstName: null
  lastName: null
  fullName: ->
    firstName = @get("firstName")
    lastName = @get("lastName")
    firstName + " " + lastName
  .property("firstName", "lastName")
)
```

As they say,make your code right.

Comment: Why the downvotes?  This answer is essentially identical to Michael Siebert's, with the bonus of explaining the process the author used.  Am I missing something?

Comment: there is a little error in my code. i should use bracket around `fullName`'value, which is a `function`.