# Trouble converting js to coffeescript

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript

I'm trying to learn ember.js (using coffeescript) but the tutorial is in js, and I am coming across some code that I can't figure out how to get into coffeescript.

I'm pretty sure the issue is coming from the how I'm wrapping the .property, but not sure how to resolve it. Thanks for help!

The js code (from http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/marking-a-model-as-complete-incomplete/):

```
Todos.TodoController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  isCompleted: function(key, value){
    var model = this.get('model');

    if (value === undefined) {
      return model.get('isCompleted');
    } else {
      model.set('isCompleted', value);
      model.save();
      return value;
    }
  }.property('model.isCompleted')
});
```

My coffeescript that gets an error (also get from Js2coffee):

```
Todos.TodoController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(
    isCompleted: (key, value) ->
        model = @get("model")
        if value is `undefined`
            model.get "isCompleted"
        else
            model.set "isCompleted", value
            model.save()
            value
    .property("model.isCompleted")
)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding a function call on the end of function in coffeescript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205434/adding-a-function-call-on-the-end-of-function-in-coffeescript) (straight out of the *Related* section of the sidebar). PS: js2coffee is buggy and out of date.

Comment: Yes, add `()` around the function before adding the `property`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parens in CoffeeScript are optional, except when you need them.

```
Todos.TodoController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(
    # add paren before function
    isCompleted: ((key, value) ->
        model = @get("model")
        if value is `undefined`
            model.get "isCompleted"
        else
            model.set "isCompleted", value
            model.save()
            value
    ).property("model.isCompleted")
)
```