# How to reproduce correct JavaScript object literal property that is an anonymous function from CoffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, syntax, coffeescript

I have the following valid javascript:

```
App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
firstName: DS.attr('string'),
lastName: DS.attr('string'),
birthday: DS.attr('date'),

fullName: function() {
    return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName');
  }.property('firstName', 'lastName')
});
```

According to [js2coffee.org](http://js2coffee.org) This js is the equivalent of the following coffee script :

```
App.Person = DS.Model.extend(
  firstName: DS.attr("string")
  lastName: DS.attr("string")
  birthday: DS.attr("date")
  fullName: ->
    @get("firstName") + " " + @get("lastName")
  .property("firstName", "lastName")
)
```

However that same coffee script does not compile back down into valid javascript.  It is not even valid coffee script as it errors with "Unexpected '.' "

How can I write valid Coffee Script that will create the same or syntactically equivalent javascript as listed above ?

Comment: Found the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464739/calling-a-method-on-a-function-definition-in-coffeescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Coffeescript:`

```
App.Person = DS.Model.extend(
  firstName: DS.attr("string")
  lastName: DS.attr("string")
  birthday: DS.attr("date")
  fullName: ( ->
    @get("firstName") + " " + @get("lastName")
  ).property("firstName", "lastName")
)
```

Which compiles to:

```
App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
  firstName: DS.attr("string"),
  lastName: DS.attr("string"),
  birthday: DS.attr("date"),
  fullName: (function() {
    return this.get("firstName") + " " + this.get("lastName");
  }).property("firstName", "lastName")
});
```

Comment: no biggie thanks for the reply. it took making the question to get the related question bar to show the answer. I had been searching for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Is there anyway to make it like this :

```
class App.Person extends DS.Model
    name: DS.attr
```

I know that it doesn't work with this syntax but I would like to use Coffee's class syntax